# Help with showing equality of quadratic matrix equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For two symetric matrices $A$ and $B$ of same dimension with compatible column vectors $a$ and $b$ I verified numerically that

$$(A^{-1}a + B^{-1}b) ^T (A - A(A+B)^{-1}A) (A^{-1}a + B^{-1}b) - a^TA^{-1}a -b^TB^{-1}b $$

simplifies to

$$(a-b)^T(A+B)^{-1}(a-b)$$

I would welcome pointers what is a good approach to derive this. I factored out the first term, but I am stuck after some steps, specifically at

$$ 2 b^TB^{-1}a + b^TB^{-1}AB^{-1}b - b^TB^{-1}b - a^T(A+B)^{-1}a  - 2 b^T B^{-1} A (A+B)^{-1}a -b^TB^{-1}A(A+B)^{-1}AB^{-1}b$$

The latter three terms are clearly related through

$$(A B^{-1} b  + a) ^T (A+B)^{-1} (A B^{-1} b  + a)$$

But this does not really help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that
$$B^{-1}A(A+B)^{-1} = B^{-1}(A+B)(A+B)^{-1} - B^{-1}B(A+B)^{-1}$$
to simplify the second-to-last term, and two iterations of the same trick to simplify the last term.

Comment: Thanks. I am still impressed that you could spot this. Did you just see this or does it resemble some known form?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any piece of stunning insight; I looked at the last two terms and thought, "there has to be a way to eliminate at least one inverse from each term."